# Range of frequencies of the Schumann resonance?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, geophysics, electromagnetism, upper-atmosphere

<sub>[Crossposted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/676624/) at Physics SE</sub>

---

As the surface-ionospheric gap acts as a resonator for electromagnetic waves, it should have several harmonic values from the base, fundamental frequency of 7.83 Hz.
These are integer multiples, but there is a limit as to how high the frequency can go for it to have an effect, especially so for the Schumann resonance, as the gap between the lithosphere and ionosphere can change due to events in space, mainly the sun.
Hence, what is the maximum range of integer frequency values for the Schumann resonance?

Comment: If anyone thinks the Earth Science Beta is too small a space for this question to be answered, I'd encourage people to share it to other SE websites themselves. Moderators do not seem to like it when a question is reposted by the same person on other SE websites.

Comment: Crossposting with a notification to the readers is perfectly fine. Also, it's been 2 months.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo. I have done as you suggested before but one of the moderators did not seem to fond of it. It is true, it has been two month since this question has been asked. Not much to loose.

Comment: Here is the site were the question was moved to if anyone is interested in following this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/676624/upper-limit-of-schumann-resonance-harmonics

Comment: I always thought crossposting at any point was bad, the question could've been highlighted in the Astronomy or Physics chat rooms to get some more input here... now we just have random incomplete questions :-(

Comment: [This Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) has more input on cross posting.  There's no hard and fast rule, but generally it's not encouraged, just because it leaves a mess.  Thank you for at least linking to it though, and waiting a while to do so. :-)

Comment: That is why I was hesitant to do it, but after two month of waiting I passed it to physics. The question at hand is interdisciplinary in nature so it is not the worst thing either